# Remove time from DateTime field

Tags: ms-access-2016

I am very new to access and have been trying to create what I am told is a pretty ambitious database, especially for a noob.  My first problem is:

After hours of searching, reading and not finding a solution I need to figure out how to strip the time field out of the DATE_TIME field.  I have to keep only unique records and if there are two records on the same date 30 seconds apart we do not consider those unique.  Just reformatting doesn't work as it still considers the time field.  I do need to keep the date.

Also where to put any code suggested as that would be helpful as well.  Access is no Excel.

Answer (score 0):

This will strip a time part:

```
Select 
    SomeFieldName, AnotherFieldName, Fix([YourDateTimeFieldName]) As DateOnly
From 
    YourTable
```

Edit. How about:

```
SELECT 
    Fix(ESD_RESULTS.DATE_TIME) As DateOnly, 
    ESD_RESULTS.LAST_NAME, 
    ESD_RESULTS.FIRST_NAME, 
    ESD_RESULTS.DEPT, 
    ESD_RESULTS.WRIST_STATUS, 
    ESD_RESULTS.LFOOT_STATUS, 
    ESD_RESULTS.RFOOT_STATUS 
FROM 
    ESD_RESULTS 
WHERE 
    Fix(ESD_RESULTS.DATE_TIME) 
        Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,1) 
        And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I have no idea what to do with it.  My current SQL code from using the build in Access drag and drops is:      SELECT ESD_RESULTS.DATE_TIME, ESD_RESULTS.LAST_NAME, ESD_RESULTS.FIRST_NAME, ESD_RESULTS.DEPT, ESD_RESULTS.WRIST_STATUS, ESD_RESULTS.LFOOT_STATUS, ESD_RESULTS.RFOOT_STATUS
FROM ESD_RESULTS
WHERE (((ESD_RESULTS.DATE_TIME) Between DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date())-1,1) And DateSerial(Year(Date()),Month(Date()),0)));

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set all times to a standard time before inserting them into the table, for example 00:00:01 (one second past midnight), so that you avoid the problem you're having altogether?
Although it would only be able to be done outside of access, if you were building an application, as far as I'm aware.